Issues Configuring Vue Router to Handle Routes Ending with .project
I'm experiencing difficulties configuring Vue Router to handle routes with a specific pattern. My goal is to have a route like /user/work.project that should be matched and handled by a specific component. However, none of the configurations I’ve tried seem to work. Here's what I’ve attempted so far:

Vue Router Configuration:


I tried using a regex pattern to match the route, but it doesn’t seem to work.

Here’s my current router setup:


import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Landing from '@/components/Landing.vue';
import Project from '@/components/Project.vue';
import PageNotFound from '@/components/PageNotFound.vue';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'landing',
        component: Landing,
    },
    {
        path: '/:username/:project(.*\\.project)$',
        name: 'project',
        component: Project,
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            const isProjectRoute = /\.project$/.test(to.params.project);
            if (isProjectRoute) {
                next();
            } else {
                next({ name: 'not_found' });
            }
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
        name: 'not_found',
        component: PageNotFound
    }
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
});

export default router;



Issues:


The browser will result in 404 error on test subjects (e.g /user/work.project)

Despite this setup, navigating to /user/work.project results in a 404 error.

The catch-all route for not_found doesn’t handle unmatched paths as expected.



Environment:


I’m using Vue 3 with Vite.

